# How to sum group totals in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need the revenue sum totals of each business which has multiple line items.  Example of the data:

[image]

Desired output:
[image]

This is what I have  which is not correct:

```
SELECT  business_name,  sum(revenue)  
FROM business_table
GROUP BY  business_name
```

Comment: What does that query yield and how is it incorrect?

Comment: The only thing missing is column alias for sum: ` as revenue`. Then query output will match desired output.

Comment: Results are yielding multiple line items instead of a total of all.  Each business name consists of revenue totals for several buildings.

Comment: @Tone, if that's the case it's almost certain that can't be the exact SQL statement you're using. Based on the sample data, and the query, it would net the results (less the field being named like others are saying).

Comment: Your query is fine [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28f40/2/0)

Comment: Please provide an example of the incorrect output. The query shown will transform the given example into the given desired output. It's not clear what's wrong without specifics.

Comment: perhaps the business_names are not equivalent - some whitespace or non-displaying characters stuck in there?

Answer (score 4):

you query seems perfect. only you can add a name for the second column:

```
SELECT  business_name,  sum(revenue) revenue
FROM business_table
GROUP BY  business_name
```

Comment: The multiple lines were due to multiple years of data in which i was unaware until some further digging.  Adding year to the group by and select statement yields the correct results.  Thank you.